# Error 500 in fresh magento 2.4.2 installation

Tags: magento, http-status-code-500

I am making a new fresh install and i get error 500

I am running a magento 2.4.2 with php 7.416 and apache

Memory limit is at 2048M
I have runned the following commands

```html
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                        // 644 permission for files

    find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                        // 755 permission for directory 

    find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;                // 777 permission for var folder    

    find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

    find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

    chmod 777 ./app/etc

    chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
```

But i still get error 500.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: I am unsure but I think one of the dependency packages of Magento recently published some dud code. I just installed a fresh copy of Magento 2.3.6 as well as 2.3.5-p2 and on both, I am unable to create an admin user via the admin:user:create or through bin/magento install. Are you having the same issue with the admin user account?

Comment: Hello and good morning!! (for me at least). No my issur is that i cant even access the site. Error 500.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for 500 is basically the web server has no permissions to load the pages from the installed magento directory. I personally faced the same issue while I was installing magento2 and it was really frustrating to see this after spending long hours at installation.
A quick fix is to add the Magento file system owner to the web server group and re-login to the user account or run bash if you are on ubuntu.

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data <user name>
```

For a hassle free and straight forward installation help, refer to the [blog](https://tryandtip.com/2021/05/16/install-magento-2-4-2-on-ubuntu-20-04/)  where I clearly explained the requirements and steps for 2.4.2

Comment: I found the issue. In plesk i had to uncheck Restrict the ability to follow symbolic links in Apache & nginx Settings. Also added fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
proxy_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_buffers 4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k; in Additional nginx directives